# AWS CDK s3 deployment changing intermediary assets bucket directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-cdk

I am trying to upload a folder to s3 which I will use it just after to create my glue job. I am using aws_s3_deployment library from CDK for this. My problem is that the code is firstly uploaded to a intermediary asset bucket and then moved to the destination bucket and the role that I am using doesn't have rights to write to the intermediate bucket. Is there a way to directly upload the packet to destination bucket or a way around to upload my code to s3 without changing my IAM role ?

To give an example of my code where I use s3deploy:

```
s3deploy.BucketDeployment(self, "DeployGlueCode",
    sources=[s3deploy.Source.asset("./job/source/")],
    destination_bucket=my_glue_bucket,
    destination_key_prefix="glue/job/"
)
```

Also I want to mention that my role has access to write/read/update/list the final s3 destination that I want to upload the code to.

Comment: Has your environment been bootstrapped?

Comment: Yes, I run cdk bootstrap, this creates the cloud formation template without any errors. Then I use cdk deploy command which that produce 'access denied'  When I remove the part where I deploy to s3, I can create the glue job via cdk, but the problem is the source code of glue is not updated.

Comment: `cdk bootstrap` doesn't just create a template, it deploys it to the environment you specify.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am pretty new to CDK and I am following a tutorial (https://cdkworkshop.com/30-python/20-create-project/500-deploy.html) but I changed the code inside to create a glue job. When I create the template via `cdd synth` there are some random parameters inside of the template that are used to upload to a random s3 bucket. I would like to change this via code or a command line interface parameter

Comment: Are you sure the environment is properly bootstrapped? You shouldn't have access issues to the asset bucket if it is. I don't think you can change the asset bucket with CDK tools.

Comment: When I run cdk bootstrap, I have a message saying that the environment has been bootstrapped. Then on the console, I see my stack too. I guess I can manually pass the asset parameters manually when I run `cdk deploy` but I feel like it's too cumbersome.

Comment: So you have enough rights to create the bucket, but not to write to it? Are you deploying to the same environment you've bootstrapped? What are you user's policies regarding S3?

Comment: I have enough rights to create/read/write/list the destination bucket. From what I understand looking to the generated template file, under the hood, this function is deploying the zip to a temp bucket, creating a lambda function, creating a a policy for the lambda, then deploying zip to the final destination. My role doesn't rights to create a policy and write/create a new temp bucket.

Comment: Did you do `cdk bootstrap` with the same profile you're using for `cdk deploy`? Because `cdk bootstrap` creates the assets bucket, and you had to have enough rights to create it. If you're using a differnet profile, your deployment profile has to have the right to assume the deployment role.